# Switching from FBML to Javascript SDK and Social Plugins

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbml, facebook-social-plugins, xfbml

This question might be somewhat open ended.

How would I go about switching from using FBML in my application to using the Javascript SDK and Social Plugins. Im dealing with a massive application so it's hard to tell how FBML was implemented and how the SDK should be implemented now. First I decided to switch this line.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

To this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Also, this piece of code (which looks like it loads the sdk) is there

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{               
//initialize
FB.init({
  appId   : myid,
  status  : true,
  cookie  : true,
  xfbml   : true
}); 
};
(
function() 
{
    var something = document.createElement('script');
    something.async = true;
    something.type = 'text/javascript';
    something.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(something);
}()
);
```

Anything else needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

In addition you need to:

1. Define an HTML element: `<div id="fb-root"></div>` inside the `<body>`.
2. Search for elements starting with `<fb:` and remove those associated with FBML.

Comment: thanks, so this means that not all <fb: tags disappear, only ones that are associated with fbml and not social plugins, right?

Comment: Correct. The social plugins are valid.

Comment: how do i determine whats associated with fbml

Comment: You have a complete list of all the FBML tags here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/. In addition, make sure these tags don't appear here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/